# jQuery: Table Short method -- How do I default to all?

Tags: jquery

I'm using this plugin: http://datatables.net/index

Is there an easy way for me to set by default that the table shows all results?

I've searched their site, with no answers.

Help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
$('#example').dataTable(
    'iDisplayLength': -1
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It was a great help.

Answer (score 0):

@Loktar.

Googling around I found some people were having an error with iDisplayLength taking a value of -1. -1 is their All command apparently.

I tested with no issues.

My code:

```
$('#certTableHome').dataTable({
     "iDisplayLength": -1
});
```